# Read file lines and get words before numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am writing a code, where I am open in the background a text file

```
f = open(FILENAME, 'r')
```

I am looking for specific line where something is written.

EXAMPLE in Document 1:

> Error you can find the Error in Section Nose  546516547 in Lower Part 211547

EXAMPLE in Document 2:

> Error the file break at you knee 3215467 in the element 51423165

SO I NEED THE WORDS BEFORE THE NUMBERS.
ANY IDEAS?
everything would help me. thank you.

Comment: So you mean, Nose Part knee and element will be the output?

Comment: yes that's right my friend

Comment: I forgot maybe to say that I am using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the `re` (regex) module from the standard library:

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+)(?=\s+\d)"  # Find words followed by space(s) and number.
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.findall(regex, line))
```

Comment: what if I found that word and look now for the number that is after that word

Comment: `regex = r"(\w+\s+\d+)"`. At this point I suggest you read up on regular expressions as understanding them will give you flexibility enough to create your own searches.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate each line and use below list comprehension:

```
>>> line = 'Error you can find the Error in Section Nose 546516547 in Lower Part 211547'
>>> line = line.split(' ')
>>> [line[i-1] for i, e in enumerate(line) if e.isdigit()]
['Nose', 'Part']
```

You can also use regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([\w]+)\s[0-9]+', line)
['Nose', 'Part']
```

Comment: I will try both 
I let you know which one or maybe none of them worked
thank you a lot

Comment: I guess you could also do `[line[i-1] for i, e in enumerate(line) if e.isdigit()]
`

Comment: Yeah, @RoadRunner thanks, really appreciate your efforts, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also transform all your words into a list of words, then you find the index of the number and you return list[index-1]